# Can you make custom constants in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

Is it possible to make custom constants in PHP, e.g. `E_ALL` or `PHP_URL_PATH`?

I'd love to be able to supply my own meaningful constant as an argument rather than a magic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Use [`define()`](http://www.php.net/define)

```
define( 'CONSTANT_NAME', 'CONSTANT_VALUE' );
```

Comment: Okay, I'm aware you can create constants? How would I go about validating that as a method argument and use it as a flag? (Hope I'm making sense)

Comment: `if ( CONSTANT !== assigned_value ) //oops!` You can check like that